# Have scale type correspond to stat output (continuous), not input (discrete)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

## Motivation

I have lots of data in the form of (binary) survey responses, where each response is assigned a weight. I'd like to easily explore the data by plotting (weighted) proportions, with (weighted) margins of error.

The stats are not the main issue; the `ggplot2` magic I'm attempting is. Below is an example that almost works™ except that I have to wrap a tiny detail inside `as.numeric()`. Which is icky. And there must be a fun and better way. Please show the way!

## Toy Data

For the purpose of this question, the weights are irrelevant, but the plumbing has to work, so here are some "weighted" coin tosses.

```
toss_data <- data.frame(
  coin_type = c("penny", "nickel"),
  outcome = as.logical(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)),
  weight = runif(10)) # not really relevant to this debugging issue
```

## Problem

The code that's needed to set things up is in the next section. Briefly, the problem I seem to run into is this:

- My "input" (`outcome`) starts life as a discrete variable.
- If I force it to become numeric at the beginning, everything works as expected.
- Otherwise, `ggplot2` wants to set things up with a *discrete* scale for `y`—which totally makes sense, except that my stat (`stat_wtd_mean()`, below) yields a *continuous* `y`.
- I generally want to follow up with a `... + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))` but that of course will then fail with `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`.

The chunk below creates the desired output. Note the use of `as.numeric()`:

```r
p <- ggplot(toss_data)
p <- p + aes(x = coin_type, y = as.numeric(outcome), w = weight) 
p + stat_wtd_mean()
```

[image: Desired output]

But here's what happens when that `as.numeric()` is omitted, and `outcome` tries to make the party all about its discrete self:

```r
p <- ggplot(toss_data)
p <- p + aes(x = coin_type, y = outcome, w = weight) 
p + stat_wtd_mean()
```

[image]

How do I avoid having to wrap `outcome` inside `as.numeric()`?

Can I override the default scale in some way? I've looked for `ggproto` clues but come up empty.

Should I (re)assign or modify aesthetic mappings or scales in some way?

I've never tried to implement my own `geom` or `stat` before, but it seems like a useful tool to have under one's belt.

I tried changing `stat_wtd_mean()` to return `list(layer(...), scale_y_continuous())` instead of just `layer(...)`, but that breaks with `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`.

Note: I want to do this by using a stat, instead of by writing a wrapper function like `chart_wtd_mean(data, ...)` that munges the data inside itself. The reason is that I want to exploit other aspects of `ggplot2`, like faceting or grouping-and-coloring, in a maximally flexible way.

Thanks for any insights!

## Reprex

In real life I have a more complex `compute_group_data()` that yields `y`, `ymin`, and `ymax`. This example is stripped down, but enough to reproduce this issue:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# given y and w, compute some (weighted) summary of y
compute_group_data <- function(data, scales) {
  grp_vars <- c(setdiff(names(scales), "y"), "PANEL", "group")
  grouped <- group_by(data, across(all_of(grp_vars)))
  df <- summarise(grouped, y = weighted.mean(y, w), .groups = "drop")
  return(df)
}

StatWtdMean <- ggproto(
  "StatWtdMean", Stat,
  compute_group = compute_group_data,
  required_aes = c("y", "w"),
  dropped_aes = c("w"))

stat_wtd_mean <- function (
    mapping = NULL,
    data = NULL,
    geom = "point",
    position = "identity",
    na.rm = FALSE,
    show.legend = NA,
    inherit.aes = TRUE,
    ...
) {
  layer(
    stat = StatWtdMean, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom,
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}

toss_data <- data.frame(
  coin_type = c("penny", "nickel"),
  outcome = as.logical(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)),
  weight = runif(10)) # not really relevant to this debugging issue

# if as.numeric() is omitted, this breaks (discrete instead of cont scale)
p <- ggplot(toss_data)
p <- p + aes(x = coin_type, y = as.numeric(outcome), w = weight) 
p + stat_wtd_mean() + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))
```

Comment: All you need to do is add `if(is.logical(grouped$y)) grouped$y <- as.numeric(grouped$y)` into your compute group function before the summarize line.

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron, but that doesn't solve the problem. I've edited the post to show the desired output as an image (and the undesired output too).

Comment: @dholstius It is unclear to me what the question is. Can you restate the question more explicitly? What is it that you want `ggplot` to do?

Comment: @dholstius This does not seem like a minimum reproducible example as there are 6 custom functions in your setup that don't seem to be related to your example dataset. This is the cause for confusion as it seems like you may need help with the functions not `ggplot`. You may want to edit your question to remove the `Setup Code` bit and just provide an example dataset of the function output that you would like help with.

Comment: @dholstius maybe I'm overthinking it, are you looking to change the scale of your continuous y-axis? If so, you can use `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,0.2)` after `stat_prop()` as an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256122/discussion-between-dholstius-and-tassones).

Comment: Your function coerces your logical variable to numeric and you want ggplot to know that even though you're feeding ggplot the logical version?

Comment: @JonSpring In a way, yes. In my use case, the stat_wtd_mean() function doesn’t coerce to numeric—it yields a numeric value derived from a vector of discrete values. I’m open to being persuaded that what I’m hoping for is misguided. For example, what should happen if another geom were subsequently added? Should it be expected to work with a continuous scale? Does it matter whether it’s added before or after stat_wtd_mean()?